# Windows Phone 7 open new email

Tags: email, windows-phone-7

How can I open new email programatically in Windows Phone 7? I found only solution with using WebBrowser control and using it Navigate method with "mailto" syntax. Is any better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.emailcomposetask(v=VS.92).aspx) is another option.